# Purpose of Wait queue in Lock

Tags: c#, multithreading

During `Monitor.Wait()` a thread moves into `wait queue` releasing the `lock`. When some other thread calls `Pulse` the waiting thread gets into ready `queue` and attempt for the `lock` again. I am trying to understand the need of wait queue. Why not simply thread moves into ready queue and wait for the lock. Any scenario which would not work if thread had moved into ready queue directly?

Comment: If multiple threads are waiting to enter a lock (Monitor actually) then you don't want to have them *all* trying to enter the lock again when it is released.  Since only one of them can win.  So Monitor keeps a queue of blocked threads, the thread at the head of the queue gets the chance to enter and almost always gets it.  It is efficient and fair, there is a guarantee that a thread always acquires the lock.

Comment: @HansPassant does it mean if a `lock` is used instead of `Monitor`, threads will incessantly keep trying, thus causing unnecessary contention, when not required.

Comment: The opposite, the wait queue prevents contention.  While almost always what you want, there are some obscure cases where it is not optimal and lock convoys are a problem.  You could then use PulseAll() and leave it to the operating system to sufficiently randomize the odds for a thread acquiring the lock.

Comment: In multi threaded environment order of threads entering into wait state is non deterministic so queue does not add much value. Moreover these queues are not guaranteed to be fair.

Comment: If thread goes into suspended state while being into wait queue then it makes sense.